# Mass/wildcarded file delete on Android

Tags: java, android, performance, filesystems

I have a folder with several hundred (up to ~6000) small files. I want to delete all files in that folder (or the whole folder) *quickly*. Preferably in O(1) time.

Is there a way to delete a nonempty folder? Alternatively, is there a way to delete multiple files (specified by a wildcarded name) *in one API call*?

I know all about `File.listFiles()` and `File.delete()`; achieving this functionality per se is easy; I'm after the performance now.

Edit: maybe from C? I already have an NDK library in the project - is there an NDK-supported syscall to that effect?

Comment: Bear in mind that what you want is unrealistic. There may be simpler APIs than iterating over the files, but it is going to be slow no matter how you accomplish it, because this is flash memory we're talking about, and the YAFFS2 filesystem on most devices as well. The overhead from the Java side is going to be completely lost in the time it takes to actually do the filesystem changes. Why not just do the work in a background thread?

Comment: You could save some time if it is realistic to keep an in memory cache of the File objects or filenames pointing to these files. But yeah, flash memory, etc.... don't think it's gonna be a huge win

Comment: @CommonsWare: what's so unrealistic about expecting that one pass over the directory will execute faster than N passes? Also, doesn't even flash memory work in blocks of several KB? And if so, changing several/all file records in a block at once will with one writeout will execute faster than a change/writeout for every file?

Comment: "what's so unrealistic about expecting that one pass over the directory will execute faster than N passes?" -- that's very possible, but you may not see a material savings depending on the implementation. "changing several/all file records in a block at once will with one writeout will execute faster than a change/writeout for every file?" -- that's conceivable. I don't think there's any call you can make that achieves your end, and there's certainly nothing at the SDK level that I can think of that will help.

Answer (score 0):

As CommonsWare said, you won't be able to get around around the fact that deleting/de-referencing files takes time and that can't be circumvented, even using C with the NDK.  Just throw it into a background task to free up the UI and hope for the best.